# OIDC-react signtOut doesn't end Cognito session

Tags: amazon-cognito, openid-connect

My stack: oidc-react, Amazon Cognito

When I log out on the site and call `auth.signOut();`, the userManager signs out the user and redirects to the login page, but when you log in again by calling `auth.signIn();` makes a request to Cognito with the token it has, but won't ask for credentials and logs the user in, I guess because the user still has a running session with the same token, if I am right. It only asks for login credentials after an hour because the session expires after 60minutes.

I want Congito to ask for credentials after signing out. I've tried passing the config these options after some research, but doesn't seem to be working:

```
revokeTokenTypes: (["access_token", "refresh_token"]),
revokeTokensOnSignout: true,
automaticSilentRenew: false,
monitorSession: true
```

This is the OIDC setup I pass to the provider:

```
    const oidcConfig: AuthProviderProps = {
        onSignIn: (user: User | null) => {
            console.log("onSignIn");
        },
        onSignOut: (options: AuthProviderSignOutProps | undefined) => {
            console.log('onSignOut');
        },
        autoSignIn: false,
        loadUserInfo: true,
        postLogoutRedirectUri: "localhost:3000/",
        automaticSilentRenew: false,
        authority: "https://" + process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_COGNITO_DOMAIN,
        clientId: process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,
        redirectUri: window.location.origin,
        responseType: 'code',
        userManager: new UserManager({
            authority: "https://" + process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_COGNITO_DOMAIN,
            client_id: process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_COGNITO_CLIENT_ID!,
            redirect_uri: window.location.origin,
            revokeTokenTypes: (["access_token", "refresh_token"]),
            revokeTokensOnSignout: true,
            automaticSilentRenew: false,
            monitorSession: true
        })
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

AWS Cognito does not yet implement the [RP Initiated Logout](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-rpinitiated-1_0.html) specification or return an `end_session_endpoint` from its OpenID Connect discovery endpoint. I expect this is your problem, since the library is probably implemented in terms of these standards.

Instead, AWS Cognito uses [these parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/logout-endpoint.html) and a `/logout` endpoint. In my apps I have implemented Cognito logout by forming a URL like this, then redirecting to it by setting `location.href` to the URL value:

```js
public buildLogoutUrl(): string {

    const logoutReturnUri = encodeURIComponent(this._configuration.postLogoutRedirectUri);
    const clientId = encodeURIComponent(this._configuration.clientId);
    return `${this._configuration.logoutEndpoint}?client_id=${clientId}&logout_uri=${logoutReturnUri}`;
}
```

This will enable you to end the Cognito session and force the user to sign in again. It will also enable you to return to a specific location within your app, such as a `/loggedout` view.